# How to ensure that a row does not have any "" in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am pretty new to R, come from a Python background. I have loaded a dataframe as such:

```
df = read.csv('data.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
colClasses = colClass,na.strings = c("NA", ""))
```

My objective is to ensure that there are no missing values in my dataframe. I was thinking of writing code as such:

```
df = na.omit(df)
```

It wasn't removing the missing values, I then realized that it could be because of the importing of the dataframe. I imported it into a dataframe where I changed the "NA" to "".

My question is, is there a function similar to NA in which  I could explicitly remove rows that have values ""?

Any help would be great!

Edit1 :Here is the first row:
[image]

Edit2: Here is the structure of the dataframe:
[image]

Comment: It would be useful to see a bit of example data, ideally exported with `dput`.

Comment: @JasonMorgan I ran dput and the first row is above.

Comment: @rmhesh `dput` should return a `structure` object, in text form, making it easy to copy-paste into the terminal for replication purposes. Not sure that that is.

Comment: @JasonMorgan Sorry about that. I ran str(df) and I have attached that to my original post.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. It is very unlikely that you have any values of `""` in your data given that you read it in using `read.csv(... na.strings = c("NA", ""))`

Comment: @Ista I would like to remove all rows that have missing values. The example that I have provided above is an example of a row that should be removed. A row that should not be removed, would be rows with no NA or "" . As to whether any values have "", I am not too sure as I have thousands of rows. I am quite new to R and from my understanding, it would have either NA or "" for missing values.

Comment: Use `na.omit` to remove rows with missing values.

Comment: @Ista Not sure what happened this time around, but that actually ended up working thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you actually asked, an anonymous function and an `apply` function will do the job.

```
df <- df[!apply(df, 1, function(x){all(x=="")}),]
```

The `apply` function applies a function either row or column wise. The second argument chooses which, so `1` means by row and `2` means by column. Finally the last bit is our custom function which returns TRUE if all the data is "" in that row. If you wanted to check for NAs you could replace `x==""` with `is.na(x)`. Finally once the `apply` returns that list of true and falses we shove that as the idex for our dataframe to get back just the rows we want.

**EDIT 2: Turns out I understood it the first time around, the below is what you want!**
**EDIT: I misunderstood your question, the below is the original answer I gave and will remove any row with at least one NA in it!**

If you're happy to leave the NAs in there the `complete.cases` function will return all rows which have an NA. i.e.

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

If you wanted to get rid of NAs you could do it after you've filtered out all the rows with strictly NAs.

```
df[is.na(df)] <- ""
```

Comment: When I run the first command, everything in my dataframe is being deleted for some reason. I know as a fact that everything is not NA. I have attached the first row of the data to an edit I made to the original post.

Comment: I misunderstood, sorry :) I've provided a new answer which should do the job!

Comment: Thanks for the answer back! Could you explain what is being done in the {all(x="")},] statement? I am sort of confused as to what the { } refer to in R. I am also getting this error: Error: unexpected ']' in "df2 <- df2[apply(df, 1, function(x){all(x=="")},]"

Comment: The error was because I missed a closing bracket on the `apply` function. I was coding blind on that one as I didn't have your data to use!

The `all` function returns TRUE if everything is TRUE. So if a vector was TRUE TRUE FALSE `all` would return FALSE. So when we check for `all(x=="")` it only returns true if every x is equal to "".

 As for the curly braces, you actually don't need them, but I like putting them in. They just encapsulate everything that's part of the function. So I make a custom function that takes x as an input, then in the curly braces put the execution.

Comment: Because I'm having a shocker today, I also forgot to put the not condition out the front. That function returns all rows that are completely empty, so we want NOT that. When it returns TRUE its referring to the rows that are completely empty. So 'not'ing that gives us what we want.

Though it's my fault, it's why we ask for minimal reproducial examples in text format. That way we can copy and paste it into our console, come up with a solution and test it before we post.

Comment: I'm essentially just using `df <- df[index, ]`. Where index is a list of true and falses, true for rows we want to keep, false for rows with only empty cells.

Comment: Thank you so much for the the help so far! Unfortunately, nothing seems to be happening to the dataframe when I run your first command. I think I understand the logic of where you are coming from. And I can try and submit minimal reproducible examples in a text format, if you could instruct as to how I can go about doing that.

Comment: So it doesn't need to look exactly like your data, but something that is essentially the same type. So I bit the bullet and made some data up, I just did this `df <- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,""), c(1,"",1,"",""), c(1,1,"",1,""))`. To the best of my understanding that's data that looks like yours. Generic dataframe with some data and some ""s. The last row of which is all ""s. Using this my code works. Perhaps double check you copied it again? I recently changed to add the not which is the `!` symbol.

Comment: Hello, thanks for getting back. I have tried copying the data, but the rows just do not seem to be deleting. I even tried switching the x=='' to is.na(x) and it is not changing any rows. The format is similar to the dataframe that you have created as an example, except I have NA in columns instead of "" (which actually should have changed).

Comment: In your main post you have an example of a row that **shouldn't** be removed, can you share an example of a row you think **should** be removed?

Comment: The example I had in my main post was an example of a row that **should** be removed. If there were no NA values in that row (which there are in the 'date' and 'registered' column) then that row would not be removed.

Comment: Wow, what a journey! In that case the very first thing I said is the solution :) It will remove any rows with an NA in it. If it returns nothing, it means all rows have an NA in it.

Comment: Thank you for your help through the process!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert empty strings to NAs, another option is `dplyr::na_if()`:

```
# example data
dat <- tribble(~col1, ~col2, 
               1, "", 
               2, "some string", 
               3, "another string")
dat
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   col1 col2          
  <dbl> <chr>         
1  1.00 ""            
2  2.00 some string   
3  3.00 another string

dat %>% 
  na_if("") %>% 
  na.omit()
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   col1 col2          
  <dbl> <chr>         
1  2.00 some string   
2  3.00 another string
```